# <div> gets an automatic width without initialization in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a maze that gets the height and width values from user. I gave a background color to maze object, but I want the background width to be the same size as the width of the maze. If the maze's width is getting bigger the background gets bigger as well. How can I do that?  this is my html code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <style type="text/css">
          .mze
          {
             color: Blue;
             text-align: center;
             background-color: Yellow;
             width: 100%;
          }
         .prompt
         {
             background-color: Yellow;
             color: Red;
         }
         </style>
         <script src="mazegenerator.js"></script>
         <title>Maze</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="maze">
        <form style="text-align: center" name="forma1">
        <br/>
            <label>
               HEIGHT:&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" id="height" name="height" autofocus="autofocus" 
              maxlength="2" size="6" value="" />
            <label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; WIDTH:&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" id="width" name="width" maxlength="2" size="6" value="" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <span id="prompt"></span>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" alt="submit" onclick="CreateMaze();" 
                   value="Generate" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="Mzobj" align="center">

        <pre id="out" class="mze"></pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the js part where I get the value from user:

```
function CreateMaze(){
//gets the value of Height & Width from user
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("width").value);
//Values of Height and Width can't be zero
if (a == 0) {
    document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML = "<b>height</b> is invalid";
    document.getElementById('prompt').className = "prompt";
    return;
}
if (b == 0) {
    document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML = "<b>width</b> is invalid";
    document.getElementById('prompt').className = "prompt";
    return;
}
//Width can't be smaller than height
if (a > b) {
    document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML = "not possible";
    document.getElementById('prompt').className = "prompt";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('prompt').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('prompt').className = "";
}

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = display(maze(a,b));
}


//Display the maze
function display(m) {
  var text= [];
  for (var j= 0; j<m.x*2+1; j++) {
    var line= [];
    if (0 == j%2)
        for (var k=0; k<m.y*4+1; k++)
            if (0 == k%4) 
                line[k]= '+';
            else
                if (j>0 && m.verti[j/2-1][Math.floor(k/4)])
                    line[k]= ' ';
                else
                    line[k]= '-';
    else
        for (var k=0; k<m.y*4+1; k++)
            if (0 == k%4)
                if (k>0 && m.horiz[(j-1)/2][k/4-1])
                    line[k]= ' ';
                else
                    line[k]= '|';
            else
                line[k]= ' ';
    if (0 == j) line[1]=line[3]=' ',line[2]= 'S';
    if (m.x*2-1 == j) line[4*m.y]= 'E';
    text.push(line.join('')+'\r\n');
}
return text.join('');
```

this is the image of what I get:

[image]

Comment: Most likely, the js you have is causing this issue

Comment: I agree with @Huangism...  The fact that the `style` attribute is being added to the `div` makes me think that it is js who is setting the width.  Look there and if you're still stuck post your js.

Comment: I already post the Js @Ballbin

Comment: Ah, yes I see that... sorry running a little slow today.

Comment: @user603948 What about the code for `display(maze(a,b))`?  Seems like the issue could be in there...

Comment: I added that part now @Ballbin

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using any brackets in your display javascript? It is hard to follow.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the width entered by the user is in pixels you can add the following code at the end of your 'CreateMaze()` function...

`document.getElementById("Mzobj").setAttribute("style", "width:" + b + "px");`

If not then you will need to figure out how to convert the entered width to a measurement that will work in an HTML page.  If it is the number of characters across then you need to figure out how many units that a character in the font takes up and calculate it. `var width = <number units per character> * <number of characters>`  The link below should help with units.

http://desource.uvu.edu/dgm/2740/IN/steinja/lessons/05/l05_03.html?m=1